# Cant pass a function to a React child from parent (through a list)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child

Im trying to pass a simple list from a parent to a set of child components and i cant pass down a function. i have something line for line that is the exact same bloody thing that works but this does not.

Does anyone see what is going wrong?

This is the function in the parent that i cant reach (the console.log is not firing):

```
setClassImage(name, image){
     console.log('inside setClassImage');
     var TitleArray = this.state.TitleArray;
     TitleArray[0] = name;
     var ImageArray = this.state.ImageArray;
     ImageArray[0] = image;
     this.setState({
       characterModal: false,
       equipmentModal: false,
       TitleArray: TitleArray,
       ImageArray: ImageArray
     });
   }
```

Setting the list in the parent:

```
   let listClasses;

           if(this.state.classResults.length!=0){
                 listClasses = this.state.classResults.map((item,i) => {
                   return (
                     <ListClass key={i} classes={item} setClassImage={this.setClassImage.bind(this)}/>
                   );
                 });
           }
```

in the render of the parent:

```
        <SelectorBox>
          <ListBox>
            {listClasses}
            <br/>
          </ListBox>
          <SelectorButton onClick={(e)=>this.cancelChange(e)}>No Class</SelectorButton>
        </SelectorBox>
```

In the child:

```
class ListClass extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={

    }
  }

  getImage(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/post2/characterimage', {
      search: this.props.classes,
    })
      .then((response)=>{
       console.log('response from the pixabay call ', response.data);
       self.props.setClassImage(self.props.classes, response.data);
      })
     .catch(()=>{
       console.log('hello axios error');
     });
  }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <ItemContainer onClick={(e)=>this.getImage(e)}>
            <p>
              {this.props.classes}
            </p>
          </ItemContainer>
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

I can see `console.log('response from the pixabay call ', response.data);` and it fires correctly from data on the backend. But the function is not called! The weirdly named containers are purely for styling, so just assume they all act like divs.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow function in your .then()  call will automatically bind this to the proper context,  so you don't need to do the var self = this;  However you do need to bind your getImage function in your constructor.  OR

Update your function definition to:

```
  ....
  getImage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/post2/characterimage', {
      search: this.props.classes,
    })
      .then((response) => {
       console.log('response from the pixabay call ', response.data);
       this.props.setClassImage(this.props.classes, response.data);
      })
     .catch(()=>{
       console.log('hello axios error');
     });
  }

  ....
}
```

Otherwise,  bind getImage in your constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};

    this.getImage = this.getImage.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but it doesn't solve the issue. I'm still not able to call the function.

Comment: @PeterWeyand   It's very likely an issue with what "this" (or self) is when the callback is invoked.  If you put a `debugger` statement right after the console.log,  you can look at what this is and whether it has the props you're expecting.  If `this` is wrong,  it will just be a case of making sure stuff if bound correctly.  I'd use the `nonLifecycleFunction = ( ) => {}` pattern everywhere.